# how to link pages in node.js

Tags: node.js, ejs

hello I am new to nodejs and I wants to link pages in node.js but it says Cannot GET /crud/create, a folder named "crud" has two files in it: index.ejs, create.ejs
 I write this code to get the page, but only index page is showing

```
  app.get('/crud', (req, res) => res.render('crud'))
```

at index page when I click on create new than it says cannot get , I am using this link to go on create page:

```
  <a href="/crud/create" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Create New</a>
```

I make a seprate path but all in vain sometimes it shows error and some time remains on same page

```
   app.get('/crud/create', (req, res) => res.render('create')) 
   app.get('/create', (req, res) => res.render('create'))
```

Comment: You need a separate path definition for `/crud/create`, EJS won't just peek into your directory and automatically map `ejs` files to paths that are available to the client.

Comment: `app.get('/crud/create', (req, res) => res.render('crud/create'))` try this

Comment: I make a seprate path but all in vain sometimes it shows error and some time remains on same page app.get('/crud/create', (req, res) => res.render('create'))
app.get('/create', (req, res) => res.render('create'))

Comment: @BinitGhetiya should you prefer to tell me that can I make a single path for all pages which are in one folder like: crud/index,create,edit,show

Comment: ```app.get('/crud/:page', (req, res) => res.render('crud/' + req.params.page))

then you can call /crud/index /crud/edit /crud/show /crud/delete``` but this is not good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a route that points to `/crud/create` in order for your tag to work.

Something like this

`app.get('/crud/create', (req, res) => res.render('crud create'))`

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: thnx and should you prefer to tell me that can I make a single path for all pages which are in one folder like: crud/index,create,edit,show

Comment: On the link I attached above, look at app.route(). With this you can create a chainable route handler. Hope this helps

Comment: I use it but its not working app.route('/crud')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.render('/create')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.render('/edit')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.render('show')
  })

Comment: Can you send a screenshot what you are getting

Comment: According to the error message,you are trying to go to a view file that does not exist,res.render('/create'), if you have a view file named 'create' remove the '/'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198636/discussion-between-shiko-meela-and-pro).